# Two web applications on a single domain

Tags: asp.net, web-services, dns, hyperlink

A client has a business application installed on their local server, with a database of their customers. I have to implement an application (web or win) which will query the database and send mails to customers based on certain rules.

However, one of the requirements is that a mail should have a link allowing their customers to confirm or cancel certain appointments, and the problem is that my client wants to have these links having the same domain as their web site, which is already hosted somewhere else.

The way I see it, the only way to do this is for them to allow me to access their existing site, and add the necessary functionality there directly, but they are no too happy about it.

Is it possible to add a separate application to that same hosting provider, which would sit in the same domain?

Or do you have a better idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use subdomains or use a subdirectory and make it an application in IIS.

1) Subdomain
Add a new website in IIS and add binding to a subdomain. So lets say their main website is www.company.com you will add binding yourwebapplication.company.com

2) in IIS select the website, right click and choose: Add Application
The website does not have to be fysically in a subfolder, it can be anywhere as long as you have the rights set correctly.

Comment: You're fast! Can you elaborate the second approach? I need to create a subdirectory in their existing web, and then make it "point" to my application, or?

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but subdomain seems like the best way to do it, I'll go with that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an IIS Virtual Directory for this.

[Create a Virtual Directory (IIS 7)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771804%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)